# Oracle xmlagg character string buffer too small

Tags: sql, oracle

Because listagg was not enough to handle more than 3k characters, I had to try xmlagg. However, it's giving me the below error when trying to execute the below code. What am I doing wrong?

```
Error report -
ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 24
19011. 00000 -  "Character string buffer too small" 
*Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back
*Action:   Get the result as a lob instead

DECLARE
    cols CLOB;--VARCHAR2(30000);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        rtrim(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(
            e, agr_name || ', '
        )
            ORDER BY
                agr_name
        ).extract('//text()'), ', ') agr_name
    INTO cols
    FROM
        dat_skills;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_dat_skills AS
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            dat_skills PIVOT (
                COUNT ( agr_name )
                FOR agr_name
                IN (]'
                      || cols
                      || q'[)
            )
        ]';
END;
```

EDIT: This is working now as per @mathguy answer.

```
SELECT
    XMLAGG(xmlelement(e, agr_name, ', ').extract('//text()')
        ORDER BY
            agr_name
    ).getclobval() agr_name
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            agr_name
        FROM
            dat_skills
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your code.

First, you are not calling the `getclobval()` method on the result of `extract()`, so what you are going to get is a `varchar2` - or an error if the resulting aggregation is too long. It **is** too long, obviously (which is why you were using `xmlagg` in the first place) so you get that error. Fix it by adding `.getclobval()` after the call to `extract(...)`.

Then, you are creating a list of strings (I assume `agr_name` is a column of type `varchar2` or similar) to use in the `in` list of `pivot`. For that to work, the "agr names" must be enclosed in single-quotes in the `in` list; your code doesn't do that. That's likely to be the second error.

Then, are the values in the `agr_name` column unique? If they are not, you will get a complaint about "column ambiguously defined" after `PIVOT` is applied. You would be trying to create several copies of the same column in the view - obviously incorrect (and not what you want).

Finally, are there other columns in your base table, which should not participate in `PIVOT`?

Forget the whole PL/SQL code; start by writing a simple `SELECT` query that does exactly what you want. You may find out that a simple `select * from ... pivot (...)` is not enough. After you make that work, write a view based on that, and make sure it works as needed. Then look at the view and try to generate **exactly** the same string in PL/SQL. Only then write the code to use `execute immediate`. Attack the issues one at a time, otherwise you will spend two weeks trying to debug this and you may still not get it 100% right.